# Error using maven-gae and google plugin for eclipse (GPE)

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

I read the the last GPE integrated well with maven projects.

So I create a maven project from cmd line using the maven-gae-plugin.

Then imported into eclipse as a maven project.

However when I run it as "Web Application" (GPE) it fails with this error:

> Unable to discover the Google App Engine SDK root but was instead loaded from file:/Users/neo/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-tools-sdk/1.6.6/appengine-tools-sdk-1.6.6.jar.  Specify -Dappengine.sdk.root to override the SDK location.

In project's Properties -> Google -> Google App Engine, I've the sdk point to /Users/neo/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.6.6/appengine-java-sdk-1.6.6 (which is a valid sdk directory).

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: As a side note: sdk 1.6.6 is a year and a half old. You should use the latest sdk: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForJavaReleaseNotes

Answer (score 1):

We also ran in the this problem.  It seems to be a class loading problem.  Simply move tools up on the list so it loads first.

1. Go to **Run** -> **Run Confiurations**...
2. Select your app under "**Web Application**"
3. Click "**Classpath**" tab
4. highlight the appengine-tools jar and choose "**Up**" so it moves above your project.

Answer (score 0):

Unzip the file appengine-tools-sdk-1.6.6.jar and it will create a folder appengine-tools-sdk-1.6.6

It will work if you put the following in VM arguments in your run configuration

-Dappengine.sdk.root=/Users/neo/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-tools-sdk/1.6.6/appengine-tools-sdk-1.6.6